# Windows 8.1 drivers for low end device

Tags: windows, usb-drivers

I have a low end device I'm trying to connect to my Windows 8.1 laptop. The device has no markings and was purchased by a friend of a friend (I think it was one of those cheap Groupon buys) and I don't have the manufacturer info as of this time.

Currently in Windows Device Manager, it is showing up in *Other Devices* as *Android*. The device status says

> The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28).

Windows couldn't automatically find an updated drive and the generic Google drivers didn't work either.

Does anybody know where else to go about finding drivers that  may work?

Here is the information that is available via Settings->About tablet:

- Model number: MID
- Android version: 4.0.4
- Baseband version: 2.1rc
- Kernel version: 3.0.8+
  tt@tt-System-Product-Name #68
  Mon Aug 5 13:36:51 CST 2013
- Build number: nuclear_evb-eng 4.0.4 IMM76D 20130725 test-keys

It's very similar (looks the same, specs are a little diff) to this [generic tablet](http://www.ebay.com/itm/130963861900)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a [Samsung driver](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201401/20140121132354500/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.33.0.exe).

- Go to Device Manager, find the Android device, and select Update Driver Software.
- Select Browse my computer for driver software
- Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
- Select ADB Interface from the list
- Select SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface (this is a signed driver). If you get a warning, select Yes to continue.
- Done!

For good measure, I ran `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`. Then when I ran `adb devices` I finally saw a device listed so I fired up IntelliJ and all is good in the world again!